# importing a default class won't let me use it's functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, export

I'm trying to import a javascript class with default export. But I cannot use the functions defined in it. An error says "Uncaught TypeError: _omise2.default.setPublicKey is not a function"

Here is the file with the class that I'm trying to import

```js
import { isUri } from 'valid-url';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class Omise {
  constructor(config) {
    const result = verifyConfigStructure(config);
    if (result.error) {
      throw new Error(result.message);
    }

    this.config = config;
    this.publicKey = null;
    this._rpc = null;
  }

  _createRpc(callback) {
    if (this._rpc) {
      return this._rpc;
    }
    else {
      const { vaultUrl } = this.config;
      const tm = setTimeout(() => {
        this._rpc.destroy();
        this._rpc = null;

        if (callback) { callback(); }
      }, 30000);

      this._rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({
        remote: `${vaultUrl}/provider`,
        onReady() {
          clearTimeout(tm);
        }
      }, {
        remote: {
          createToken: {}
        }
      });

      return this._rpc;
    }
  }

  setPublicKey(publicKey) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
    return this.publicKey;
  }

  createSource(type, options, callback) {
    const auth = btoa(this.publicKey);

    options.type = type;
    
    const url = `${this.config.interfaceUrl}/sources/`;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(options),
    })
    .then(response => (
      response
        .json()
        .then(data => callback(response.status, data))
    ))
    .catch((error) => {
      callback(0, {
        code: 'create_source_error',
        error: error.message,
      })
    });
  }

  createToken(as, attributes, handler) {
    const data = {};
    data[as] = attributes;

    this._createRpc(() => {
      handler(0, {
        code: 'rpc_error',
        message: 'unable to connect to provider after timeout'
      });
    }).createToken(this.publicKey, data, (response) => {
      handler(response.status, response.data);
    }, (e) => {
      handler(e.data.status, e.data.data);
    });
  }
}

/**
 * Helper to verify config structure.
 * @param {Object} config - config for omise.js.
 */
export function verifyConfigStructure(config) {
  const result = {
    error: false,
    message: '',
  };

  if (!config.vaultUrl || !isUri(config.vaultUrl)) {
    result.message = 'Missing valutUrl';
  }
  else if (!config.cardHost || !isUri(config.cardHost)) {
    result.message = 'Missing cardHost';
  }
  else if (!config.cardUrl || !isUri(config.cardUrl)) {
    result.message = 'Missing cardUrl';
  }
  else if (!config.interfaceUrl || !isUri(config.interfaceUrl)) {
    result.message = 'Missing interfaceUrl';
  }

  result.error = result.message !== '';

  return result;
}
```

And here is where I'm importing it

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Alert, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, FormGroup, Label, Input, CardFooter, Button } from 'reactstrap';

import Omo from '../../lib/omise.js/dist/omise';

class CardDetails extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleCardInputChange = this.handleCardInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCardSubmit = this.handleCardSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleCardSubmit() {
    console.log(Omo);
    Omo.setPublicKey('pkey_test_5c3wgv7fgu8weckek64');
    const card = {
      name: this.state.card.ccname,
      number: this.state.card.ccnumber,
      expiration_month: this.state.card.ccmonth,
      expiration_year: this.state.card.ccyear,
      security_code: this.state.card.cccvv,
    };
    Omo.createToken('card', card, (statusCode, response) => {
      if (statusCode === 200) {
        // Success: send back the TOKEN_ID to your server to create a charge.
        // The TOKEN_ID can be found in `response.id`.
        console.log('success Response');
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        // Error: display an error message. Note that `response.message` contains
        // a preformatted error message. Also note that `response.code` will be
        // "invalid_card" in case of validation error on the card.

        // Example Error displaying
        Alert(`${response.code} : ${response.message}`);
      }
    });
  }
  handleCardInputChange(event) {
    console.log('----event----');
    console.log(event);
    const { target } = event;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    console.log('---------value--------');
    console.log(value);
    const { name } = target;

    this.setState({
      card: {
        [name]: value,
      },
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs="12" sm="6">
          <Card>
            <CardHeader>
              <strong>Credit Card</strong>
              <small> Form</small>
            </CardHeader>
            <CardBody>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="12">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="name">Name</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="ccname" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required onChange={this.handleCardInputChange} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="12">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="ccnumber">Credit Card Number</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="ccnumber" id="ccnumber" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" required onChange={this.handleCardInputChange} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col xs="4">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="ccmonth">Month</Label>
                    <Input type="select" name="ccmonth" id="ccmonth" onChange={this.handleCardInputChange} >
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                      <option value="6">6</option>
                      <option value="7">7</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="9">9</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                      <option value="11">11</option>
                      <option value="12">12</option>
                    </Input>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="4">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="ccyear">Year</Label>
                    <Input type="select" name="ccyear" id="ccyear" onChange={this.handleCardInputChange} >
                      <option>2017</option>
                      <option>2018</option>
                      <option>2019</option>
                      <option>2020</option>
                      <option>2021</option>
                      <option>2022</option>
                      <option>2023</option>
                      <option>2024</option>
                      <option>2025</option>
                      <option>2026</option>
                    </Input>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col xs="4">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label htmlFor="cvv">CVV/CVC</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="cccvv" id="cvv" placeholder="123" required onChange={this.handleCardInputChange} />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </CardBody>
            <CardFooter>
              <Button onClick={this.handleCardSubmit}>Submit</Button>
            </CardFooter>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

export default CardDetails;
```

I'm trying to use the setPublicKey function and createToken function and the above error comes.

I'm importing the javascript file created after running npm run build instead of the original Omise.js file. Am I importing it the wrong way?

Comment: `Omo`, as imported, is a *class*, not an instantiation of that class. You're never using `new`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried instantiating and here is how I have implemented it

Comment: I will post it in a new answer @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not instantiate the class after you imported it. You can only access `static` class members that way.

```
...
handleCardSubmit() {
  // Instantiate the class
  const omo = new Omise(config);
  // Then use the methods
  omo.setPublicKey('pkey_test_5c3wgv7fgu8weckek64');
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but I get the error `"_omise2.default is not a constructor"

Comment: I solved it using output.libraryTarget to umd:

` output: {
  filename: '[name]',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
  libraryTarget: "umd"
}, `  in Webpack configuration. Here is the reference `"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219943/default-is-not-a-constructor-with-a-imported-js-plugin"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented it @CertainPerformance

```js
import Omo from '../../lib/omise.js/dist/omise';
import Config from '../../lib/omise.js/src/config';

class CardDetails extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleCardInputChange = this.handleCardInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleCardSubmit = this.handleCardSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleCardSubmit() {
    const Omise = new Omo(Config);
    console.log(Omo);
    Omise.setPublicKey('pkey_test_5c3wgv7fgu8weckek64');
```

Sorry for my lack of knowledge in this. Now I get the error "_omise2.default is not a constructor"